# Applying autocorr on a bunch of series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains several time series:

```
df.head()
             0         1         2
time                              
0.0   0.365035  0.365035  0.365035
1.0   0.349999  0.349999  0.349999
2.0   0.340998  0.340998  0.340998
3.0   0.333877  0.333877  0.333877
4.0   0.326411  0.326411  0.326411
```

Now  I would like to compute for each of these the `std` and `autocorr`.

I know that I can do it individually:

```
df[0].aggregate(['std', 'autocorr'])
Out[10]: 
std         0.081165
autocorr    0.995285
```

For `std`, it works:

```
df.unstack().groupby(level=0).aggregate(['std'])
Out[11]: 
        std
0  0.081165
1  0.081165
2  0.081165
```

But when I try to do the same thing for `autocorr`, I get

```
df.unstack().groupby(level=0).aggregate(['autocorr'])
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'autocorr' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

Why is this happening? What's the correct way/workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably `autocorr` wasn't implemented as a method for the `SeriesGroupBy` class.

Try this instead:

```
In [15]: df.unstack().groupby(level=0).agg(['std', pd.Series.autocorr])
Out[15]:
        std  autocorr
0  0.014972  0.991893
1  0.014972  0.991893
2  0.014972  0.991893
```